# launch special update wizard from console

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

is there a possibility to launch the update wizard "Scan for old "" syntax in richtext and text fields and update to "" from console?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Typo3 console is able to execute all upgrade wizards. 
Use upgrade:list to se the Wizards 
And upgrade:wizard to excecute the Wizard 
https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/blob/master/Documentation/CommandReference/Index.rst#upgradelist

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this case it does not work - or more precisely: it would work when I first in the install tool manually mark the upgrade wizard as undone: https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/issues/538 If I has to mark it as undone i can start it manually of course ... :-) I am now looking for a possiblity to automate the undone mark.

Comment: As far as i know the wizzards "done" status is stored in sys registry or in local configuration (Depending on typo3 version). Typo3 console offers a configuration:set to set localconfiguration values and database:import which allows you to execute any query against the typo3 db. Wirh this unsetting should be easy.